# SAP Scripting enabled on server side?

Tags: script, sap

In oder to enable scripting, the setting `sapgui/user_scripting` must be set to `TRUE` via transaction `RZ10` for the instance profile on the SAP server side.

For me as a SAP user, is it safe to say that this setting is enabled when I see "Scripting support installed" in the SAPLogon options like this (sorry, it's German)?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting in SAPGUI just tells you whether support for scripting has been installed or not. The fact that it says it's installed and enabled doesn't give you any information about the system parameter sapgui/user_scripting.

The parameter can be checked with transactions RZ10 and RZ11 or via report "RSPARAM".

I just checked this on a system with sapgui/user_scripting set to "FALSE". In SAPGUI settings I can still enable scripting and it shows scripting support is installed.